# Export model to .xlsx observance of SOLID principles

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

*Sorry my English please!*

My DB has two tables with results of tests:

**dbo.Result**
[image]

Second table has just information about schools:

**dbo.School**
[image]

Such records probably will be 40.000-70.000. At the end I need to get report-file (pdf) like this:

[image]

**My solution:**

1. Create Excel-temple;
2. Import data from DB and export in this Excel-temple;
3. Save as .pdf;
4. Then step 1 for each record (people).

[image]

**LearnerReport.cs**

```
namespace so16092016.Models
{
    public class LearnerReport
    {
        public string SNS { get; set; } //Surname Name SecondName
        public string SchoolName { get; set; }
        public string ClassName { get; set; }
        public int TestResult5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace so16092016
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            resultsEntities context = new resultsEntities();
            ResultsRepository resultsRepository = new ResultsRepository(context);
            var ma_results = resultsRepository.GetTList().Where(x => x.SubjectCode == 2); //получить результаты по математике

            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Excel.Workbook book_template = app.Workbooks.Open(@"шаблон_отчета.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet sheet_template = book_template.Sheets["отчет"];

            foreach(var ob in ma_results)
            {
                //1. Создаем объкт LearnerReport из БД
                LearnerReport report = new LearnerReport
                {
                    SNS = $"{ob.surname} {ob.name} {ob.SecondName}",
                    SchoolName = ob.SchoolName,
                    ClassName = ob.ClassName,
                    TestResult5 = ob.TestResult5                     
                };

                //2. Экспорт объкта LearnerReport в шаблон xlsx
                sheet_template.Range["C4"].Value2 = report.SNS;
                sheet_template.Range["C5"].Value2 = report.SchoolName;
                sheet_template.Range["C6"].Value2 = report.ClassName;
                sheet_template.Range["C9"].Value2 = report.TestResult5;

                //3. Сохраняем полученный файл в .pdf на рабочем столе
                string file_name = $@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\{report.SNS}.pdf";
                sheet_template.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, file_name);
            }

            book_template.Close(0);
            book_template = null;
            app.Quit();
            app = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**What i need:** App work good and get me right results-reports. But as you see code is not good for OOP/SOLID. Therefor it is hard to scale. Help me/show right pattern to diced this task:

- logical of export to .xls have to be method of model or need create
  separated class-manager for this?
- which must to be model-report via object of database?

Comment: Do you know anything about Reflection?  You could always create an export class that accepts an object or a list of objects, utilises reflection to establish the property names and values.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756869/c-sharp-generic-excel-exporter-using-reflection

Comment: Also check out this link (from the above link), someone else has done the hard work so you don't have to :) http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: You can also look into SQL Server Report Builder and SSRS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255291.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one possible improvement is to extract export logic to the separate service:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        resultsEntities context = new resultsEntities();
        ResultsRepository resultsRepository = new ResultsRepository(context);
        var ma_results = resultsRepository.GetTList().Where(x => x.SubjectCode == 2); //получить результаты по математике

        IReportService reportService = new ExcelReportService();

        reportService.GenerateReport(ma_results);
    }

    public interface IReportService
    {
        void GenerateReport(IEnumerable<StudentDto> students);
    }

    public class ExcelReportService:IReportService
    {
        public void GenerateReport(IEnumerable<StudentDto> students)
        {
            Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
            app.DisplayAlerts = false;
            Excel.Workbook book_template = app.Workbooks.Open(@"шаблон_отчета.xlsx");
            Excel._Worksheet sheet_template = book_template.Sheets["отчет"];

            foreach (var ob in students)
            {
                //1. Создаем объкт LearnerReport из БД
                LearnerReport report = new LearnerReport
                {
                    SNS = $"{ob.surname} {ob.name} {ob.SecondName}",
                    SchoolName = ob.SchoolName,
                    ClassName = ob.ClassName,
                    TestResult5 = ob.TestResult5
                };

                //2. Экспорт объкта LearnerReport в шаблон xlsx
                sheet_template.Range["C4"].Value2 = report.SNS;
                sheet_template.Range["C5"].Value2 = report.SchoolName;
                sheet_template.Range["C6"].Value2 = report.ClassName;
                sheet_template.Range["C9"].Value2 = report.TestResult5;

                //3. Сохраняем полученный файл в .pdf на рабочем столе
                string file_name = $@"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)}\{report.SNS}.pdf";
                sheet_template.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, file_name);
            }

            book_template.Close(0);
            book_template = null;
            app.Quit();
            app = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be easier to save the Excel template in a format that is easier to edit without Excel like

- `XML Spreadsheet 2003 (*.xml)`
- `Single File Web Page (*.mht,*.mhtml)`
- `Web Page (*.htm,*.html)`

You can use placeholders in the Template like `{report.SNS}` and replace them in the XML/HTML, or in Excel with something like:

```
for(;;) 
{
    var cell = sheet_template.UsedRange.Find("{*}", Type.Missing, XlFindLookIn.xlValues, 
        XlLookAt.xlWhole, XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, XlSearchDirection.xlNext);

    if(cell == null) break; 

    var value = cell.Value2 as string;
    switch (value)
    {
        case "{report.SNS}": cell.Value2 = report.SNS; break;
     // case "{report.SchoolName}": .. etc.

        default: // log issue
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree - it will be easy and fast. But after edit how I can convert xml to pdf? And sometimes I use chart in my excel-template. Anyway I have to use Excel App, is'n it?

Comment: @adamshakhabov If you use charts or other dynamic content that depends on those values then yes, the easiest way will probably be to open in Excel to convert to pdf. There are other ways to convert to pdf without using Excel, but I don't know any to recommend.